# how qsort function from the c programming language works

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, swap, qsort

I'm reading *The C Programming Language* by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie.
I've reached chapter 5.6, where he explains the shell sort function using pointers to pointers.

I'm not getting, in the code example he gives, how the `qsort` function works:
from what I understood, `++last` will be equal to `i`?? Are we here swapping the same cell?? It's not making a sense for me.

Here's the code for the two functions:

```
/* qsort: sort v[left]...V[right] into increasing order */
void qSort(void *v[], int left, int right, funcP comp)
{
    int i, last;

    void swap(void *v[], int, int);

    if (left >= right)             /* do nothing if array contains */
        return;                    /* fewer than two elements */
    swap(v, left, (left + right) / 2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
        if ((*comp)(v[i], v[left]) < 0)
            swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last);
    qSort(v, left, last - 1, comp);
    qSort(v, last + 1, right, comp);
}

}
```

````
void swap(void *v[], int i, int j)
{
    void *temp;

    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}```
````

Comment: The easiest thing to do is put a `printf("%d %d\n", i, j)` in the `swap` function, and you'll see what's being swapped.

Comment: user3386109 is helping; your question is broader than it should be, as you have not narrowed down a specific piece of code to ask about. Printing information about what is being swapped will help illustrate how the routine works, and that is investigation you should be doing prior to asking on Stack Overflow. When referring to a book, give a complete bibliographic citation. There are two editions of The C Programming Language, and section 5.6 is different in them. The second edition has a `qsort` routine in section 5.6…

Comment: … On the page prior to the `qsort` listing, it tells you a quicksort routine was presented in chapter 4, and the new version in 5.6 is an adaptation of that for lines of text, using pointers. In section 4.10, it tells you a quicksort choses one element and then partitions the other elements into two subsets, those less than the partition element and those greater than or equal to it. The version there has some additional comments. You should examine that to see how it is partitioning the elements. Then, if you have a specific question about a single piece of code there, maybe ask about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm reading The C Programming Language by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie. I've reached chapter 5.6, where he explains the shell sort function using pointers to pointers.

Note that the code presented in the question implements the Quicksort algorithm, not Shell sort.

> I'm not getting, in the code example he gives, how the `qsort` function works: from what I understood, `++last` will be equal to `i`?? Are we here swapping the same cell?? It's not making a sense for me.

It may be that `++last` is equal to `i`.  In that case, the swap has no net effect.  But the first time the comparison function returns a result that is greater than or equal to 0, `i` will increase without `last` increasing (take note of the `if` statement), so that `i` is equal to `last + 2`. For the rest of that execution of `qsort`, `i` will be at least that far in advance of `last`, so that `++last` is *not* equal to `i`.  For random data, there will typically be many such events, so that `i` continues to get farther and farther ahead of `last`.

Overall, the function rearranges the given array elements into two groups, with all the elements of one less than or equal to all the elements of the other.  Then it recurses to do the same job on each of the two groups it just formed.

Answer (score 1):

YES it may move a value to itself.

NO `++last` is not equal to `i`.

`qsort` AKA quicksort - there are many versions on the web.
Go back to K&R chapter 4's version first, the 5.6 version is just to demonstrate pointers.
Replace the word "last" with "pivot" then
take a peek at the wiki - google search "quick sort".

ALGOLRYTHM, generalized -

```
select a pivot value, save it somewhere
now classify the rest of the partition as high or low
restore the pivot value to be between the list of lows and the list of highs
```

example ?=unknown L=low H=high P=pivot

```
???????? to start
???P???? select Pivot value
P??????? swap the pivot value with the initial value: i.e. save it
LP?????? or PH?????? next step
several repeats
PHHHHHHH or LLLLLLLP or something like LLLPHHHH 
finally
some versions LLLLHHHP
some versions PLLLLHHH
a few         LLLPLHHH
the last step swaps the last low or high with the Pivot
so            PLLLLHHH, after swap LLLLPHHH
or            LLLLHHHP, after swap LLLLPHHH
or            LLLPLHHH, after swap LLLLPHHH
exact detail depends on version
```

Always P winds up in it's final position.
`recursing` to solve two new partitions LLLL and HHH.

This is why I think of qsort as classification sort, since it simply classifies all values in a partition as high or low relative to the selected pivot. Qsort is a poor choice for large sorts, as it can go Quadratic (aprox 1/2(N^2)) but is usually faster than (N log N) time. Note also that most versions of qsort are unstable on duplicate keys.